# Way to check if Pivot needs to be refreshed (or has underlying data)

Tags: excel, vba

I have several pivots in my worksheet and I already set `RefreshTable` upon `Workbook_Open`.

However, I would like make sure that the user will be force to refresh it (just once) by adding validation with my Combo Box Control Change to check if pivot has been refreshed or not. This is where I stuck.

By the way, `.SaveData` on all pivots are set to `False` to conserve file size. I know that if I turn this on, my problem will be fixed. But I want to see if still have other option for this.

Is there a way to check if the pivot was updated/refreshed?

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    Set rng = Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1:" & Col_Letter(LastColumn) & LastRow)
    For Each pvt In shSource.PivotTables
       'confirm here if pivot has been refreshed or not
       If '???  
           'do nothing
       Else:
           pvt.ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rng)
           pvt.SaveData = False
           pvt.RefreshTable
       End if
    Next pvt
Next ws
```

**Edit #1:**
I can't rely on comparison of previous `SourceData` as there's a possibility that there is no changes in the data but still need to refresh the pivot upon opening of the file (due to `.SaveData` set to `False`)

**Edit #2:**
Seems I got a temporary workaround for this. It is a little bit messy but works. I get it by looking for the `Err.Description` and refresh it once confirmed pivot were not refreshed.

```
For Each pvt In shSource.PivotTables
    On Error Resume Next
    x = pvt.PivotCache.MemoryUsed
    If Err.Description = "The PivotTable report was saved without the underlying data. Use the Refresh Data command to update the report." Then
       pvt.ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rawDataRng)
       pvt.SaveData = False
       pvt.RefreshTable
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the datetime that the pivot was last refreshed with `pvt.RefreshDate` - so you could then either compare that with 'now' and:

Check how long since the last refresh - in this example if it's more than 10 mins ago:

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    Set Rng = Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1:" & Col_Letter(LastColumn) & LastRow)
    For Each pvt In shSource.PivotTables
       If ((Now() - pvt.RefreshDate) * 3600) < 10 Then
           'Do nothing
       Else:
           pvt.ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Rng)
           pvt.SaveData = False
           pvt.RefreshTable
       End If
    Next pvt
Next ws
```

Alternatively, you could create a `Workbook.Open` event that stores the opening time of the Workbook somewhere, and compare that against the `.RefreshDate` - but you'll need to factor in the time difference between the workbook opening and the refreshes finishing.

Comment: The `.RefreshDate` is a good solution, however i'm trying to avoid it as it was connected to the selection change. I am thinking of a function that checking the properties of the pivot if it has underlying data or not. Then I'll proceed with that.

Btw, I already set the `RefreshTable` upon `Workbook_Open` and above will just an additional measure to confirm if the pivot were updated or not.

Comment: I can't see your data, but could you not just count the number of non-blank cells in a column where the Pivot sits? If no refresh has taken place then (I assume) there would be no data visible, just any filters and headers?

Comment: The `SourceData` itself is in the `Workbook` so the pivot still shows the data but can't do anything until it was refreshed. The pivot `.SaveData` were set to `False`, it needs to be refreshed before changing anything (filters, fields).

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for a property that tells you the size of the cache?

Comment: Somehow, yes (or probably, a property that says _The pivot should be refresh as it was saved without the underlying data_). Sorry if i'm not clear with that.